# Find the Inverse function of f. $f(x)=1+\sqrt{1+x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

I found the Inverse of the function, $f^{-1}(x)= x^2-2x$. The back of my pre-cal book gives me the inverse of the function and the domain.

What I don't understand is, how the domain comes to be $x \geq 1$.

Can someone show me the steps onto how to get the domain?

Comment: Are you certain the domain isn't $x\ge -1$?

Comment: @abiessu That is the domain of $f$, not of $f^{-1}$ ;)

Comment: Yup, saw that just after I commented :-P

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Domain of $f^{-1}$= Range of $f$.

Note that the reason why we need this restriction is that $y=1+\sqrt{1+x} \geq 1$.
Without this restriction, the function $f(x)=x^2-2x$ is not one to one, thus cannot be the inverse of something ;)

Comment: Oops, I think you mean for $y = 1 + \sqrt{x + 1}\geq 1$

Comment: So what you are saying is that because it starts at the y value 1 when x is equal to zero, that is where it ultimately begins? Pardon me, just trying to understand this.

Comment: @Xero1   No, I am saying that when you calculate the inverse function you start at $y=1+\sqrt{x+1}$ then you get $y-1=\sqrt{x+1}$ and then square. The problem appears when you square, because $y-1=\sqrt{x+1}$ only makes sense if $y-1 \geq 0$, but once you square, $(y-1)^2=x+1$ actually makes sense for all $y$...The extra solutions are coming from $y-1=-\sqrt{x+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = 1+ \sqrt{1+x}$, then presumably the domain is $x \ge -1$, or $[-1,\infty)$. The range can be seen to be $[1,\infty)$.

Here is a plot of $f$:

[image]